# How interupt() method works in java thread?

Tags: java

I know how to interrupt a thread.  But I want to know how interrupt method works internally in java multi threading ?

Comment: The best way is to read the code. In simple terms it sets a volatile boolean however it can also cause blocking operations to throw Exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplistic answer. If the thread is in a wait condition, an InterruptedException is thrown. If the thread is active, the thread's interrupted flag is set.